General theorem for the differentiability of fixed points
Some years ago, the following question about the differentiability of fixed points was asked here: Differentiability of fixed points
The question was: Let $f(x,\epsilon)\in\mathbb{C}^1\left(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}\right)$ be a function s.t. there exists $k\in(0,1)$ s.t. it holds for all $x,y,\epsilon$ that $$\left|f(x,\epsilon)-f(y,\epsilon)\right|\leq k|y-x|.$$ How one can prove that the fixed point $g(\epsilon)$ with $g(\epsilon)=f\left(g(\epsilon),\epsilon\right)$ is differentiable in $\epsilon$?
It was established that one can prove this statement with the implicit function theorem. My question is now whether there exists some theorem in the literature about the differentiability of fixed points (which potentially uses the implicit function theorem) from which the statement above would follow. Or does the differentiability follow that easily from the implicit function theorem that there is no citable theorem for that?
